# HTML preview on VSCode won't change color

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

As the title says, it won't change the colors according to the changes that i have made. I have checked on the website and it changes color but the HTML preview extension. Does anyone know how to fix this? asking for a friend.

Comment: it only monitors the html file changes, just select `Preview HTML` command again to see CSS changes

Comment: @rioV8 may i know what extension to use? because mine doesn't have that option

Comment: What command did you use to Start the preview, call it again

Comment: @rioV8 ctrl+k v for side preview

Comment: then apply that again